# How to share the $scope variable of one controller with another in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have this:

```
app.controller('foo1', function ($scope) {
  $scope.bar = 'foo';
});
app.controller('foo2', function ($scope) {
  // want to access the $scope of foo1 here, to access bar
});
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: You can find a very clear answer posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: @AlankarChoudhary Ah yes, though the accepted answers for the questions seem to vary a fair bit, so perhaps this does not warrant a close.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use an Angular Service to share variable acrosss multiple controllers.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.service('User', function () {
    return {};
})
```

To share the data among independent controllers, Services can be used. Create a service with the data model that needs to be shared. Inject the service in the respective controllers.

```
function ControllerA($scope, User) {
    $scope.user = User;
    $scope.user.firstname = "Vinoth";
}

function ControllerB($scope, User) {
    $scope.user = User;
    $scope.user.lastname = "Babu";        
}
```

Comment: What does `$scope.user = User;` without quotes do?

Comment: Ah, right. I also have a route parameter argument in `ControllerA`, so how would I add that in as well?

Comment: what if i dont want to use service or factory ??
is there a way around

Comment: @SagarDevanga: Pub/Sub Model

Comment: I know this is an older post but was a lifesaver!

Answer (score 11):

You just can use [$emit/$broadcast](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for translate changes of data from one controller scope to another. Or just store these variables on $rootScope.

Comment: An answering with an example is a more helpful answer

Answer (score 5):

```
app.controller('foo2', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$$prevSibling.bar="bar"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller("firstCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.func = function () {
        // pass scope variable(s) here
        $scope.$broadcast('parentmethod', { key: value });
    }
})

app.controller("secondCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('parentmethod', function (event, args) {
        // access scope variable using args
        $scope.targetVar = args.key;
    })
})
```