# Binding ngmodel to a value that is received from the java controller

Tags: java, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

How do i bind a value that is received  in the .jsp from a java class(using model map add attribute method) to ng-model in angular js?
I have tried the below options but the value is not being fetched into the model.

```
  1) <input ng-show=true name="emailId" id="check" type="text"
                ng-model= "user.name" ng-init="user.name=${UserName}">
  2)<input ng-show=true name="emailId" id="check" type="text"
                ng-model= "user.name" ng-init="user.name={{UserName}}">
```

Comment: how about `value=${UserName}`? assuming `UserName` is a variable you added in ModelMap in your Java Controller..

Comment: Thank you so much  redflar3. it works fine now.

Comment: I basically wanted to use the two way binding capability of the ng-model to fetch the value that is obtained from the java class into the controller,put it in rootscope so that the value is accessible in all the controllers. I think this is not an efficient way of doing it.Is there any other method that can be used to pass the value from the jsp to make it available for multiple controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see value attribute there at your input element.

```
<input ng-show=true name="emailId" id="check" type="text" value = ${UserName}
                ng-model= "user.name" ng-init="user.name=${UserName}">
```

As said in comments either map your value to `user.name` or `${UserName}`. Since in your ng-init you are mapping `user.name` modlel to your jQuery `${UserName}`.

Comment: I basically wanted to use the two way binding capability of the ng-model to fetch the value that is obtained from the java class into the controller,put it in rootscope so that the value is accessible in all the controllers. I think this is not an efficient  way of doing it.Is there any other method that can be used to pass the value from the jsp to make it available for multiple controllers?

Comment: @Batman: You can put that into a service and make it available in all controllers... that's another approach which is not costly. Look at my answer given here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584342/how-do-i-access-the-scope-variable-of-one-controller-from-another-in-angular-js/22584430#22584430

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.I am new to angular and this really helped me.